# Opening page of newly created project is blank

Tags: angular

I just installed Angular, created a project as per instructions from
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-up-and-running-with-angular-on-windows-7405ba745c25/

Upon starting the local server and entering http://localhost:4200 I
get a blank display page.

I have no idea where to look for the problem.
I was told by an Angular developer that this happens a lot but she did not know what causes it.

The source of the blank page is.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FirstAngularProject</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script></body>
</html>
```

I have no idea where to start looking for the problem.  Any help would be appreciated

I saw no error messages but again I'm new at Angular I may not know where to look.

Comment: Are you familiar with a browser's inspector such as Chrome's DevTools? You can use that tool to give us more information.

Comment: Check which folder you are in when you started the app. Make sure it is the root and not deeper in the structure. Also check the dev tools (F12) to check for errors in the console or any 404s from resources

Comment: You may have something else running on port 4200.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project with angular cli is easy. You just need to run these commands after installing nodejs

```
npm install --global @angular/cli   ---> for installing angular cli 
ng new myAppName   --> for creating a new project
ng serve --> starting the project.

Now Visit localhost:4200
```